# Polymer custom element javascript data binding errors with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am currently trying to use a firebase query that returns an object and do a `dom-repeat` on the data returned. My testing element currently looks like this:

```html
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- App imports -->
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../styles/app-theme.html">

<!-- Firebase script -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCsZHdalcUQgkhmAkIsnJ66ltkgNakOh20",
    authDomain: "church-of-our-savior-oatlands.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://church-of-our-savior-oatlands.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "church-of-our-savior-oatlands.appspot.com",
  };
  var firebaseWorker = firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


<dom-module id="custom-content">
  <template>

    <span value="[[type]]" id="dummytype"/>
    <h1 class="page-title">[[type]]s</h1>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="posts">

      <style>
        :host {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      </style>

      <paper-card elevation="1">
        <p>{{item}}</p>
        <h1 class="page-title" tabindex="-1">{{item.titl}}</h1>
        <h3>{{item.author}}</h3>
        {{item.cont}}
      </paper-card>

    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-content',
      porperties: {
        posts: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
        var postsRef = firebase.database().ref("/" + this.$.dummytype.value + "/").orderByKey();
        var titls = [];
        var authors = [];
        var conts = [];
        postsRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(postSnapshot) {
            titls.push(postSnapshot.val().titl);
            authors.push(postSnapshot.val().author);
            conts.push(postSnapshot.val().contents);
          });
          //document.querySelector('template').items = posts;
          this.posts.titl = titls;
          this.notifyPath('posts.titl', this.posts.titl);
          this.posts.author = authors;
          this.notifyPath('posts.author', this.posts.author);
          this.posts.cont = conts;
          this.notifyPath('posts.cont', this.posts.cont);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

A live version of the site can be found here:
http://church-of-our-savior-oatlands.firebaseapp.com

The element is imported on the sermons and meditations tabs.

The current console errors from polymer and firebase are as follows:

`Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON`

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. .ready/<@http://localhost:5000/elements/custom-content/custom-content.html-1.js:23:11
g.Ub/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:179:537
Tb@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:53:165
uc@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:33:215
vc@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:32:837
g.Hb@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:217:287
g.wd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:152:246
qg.prototype.wd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:142:359
sg/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:140:278
cg@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:124:462
$f.prototype.open/this.La.onmessage@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:123:245
EventHandlerNonNull*$f.prototype.open@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:122:444
setTimeout handler*rg@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:137:181
qg@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:136:1071
Pg/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js:157:481
td/e.child</e.Aa<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:52:489
Cd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:56:215
yd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:56:100
H.prototype.Pd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:55:401
id@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:474
Async*ed/dd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:222
hd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:101
zd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:55:224
ld@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:54:146
H/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:824
dg/</<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:127:131
S.prototype.Ae/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:123:366
Yd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:71:245
h.dispatchEvent@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:69:395
Fe@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:85:68
L.prototype.re@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:83:442
L.prototype.kd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:83:404
EventHandlerNonNull*L.prototype.send@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:79:315
S.prototype.Ae@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:124:37
Zf@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:122:333
dg/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:127:93
H@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:803
dg@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:127:73
R/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:135:163
td/e.child</e.Aa<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:52:489
Cd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:56:215
yd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:56:100
H.prototype.Pd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:55:401
id@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js:49:474
```

`TypeError: this.posts is undefined`

The thing that bugs me most is that I have followed the documentation on both the firebase website and polymer-project website to the "T" and still can't get this to work. I resent polymerfire, if you give me a working example I'll try it, but I could never get polymerfire to work.

P.S. ~ I know I left the api key in the snippet...this is ok. It is web facing on the site anyway.

Comment: 1.  custom-element defines a property called posts that is an array.  That is not updated anywhere in your code.  2.  In a callback function such as postRef.on("value", function(){...}) scope of this is not the calling function but the callback function so this.posts doesn't exist is correct.  The "this" part is the callback function and not custom-element  3.  Your template repeat expects an array of objects but in your code you're extracting out the properties of the object into separate arrays for each field...that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really strongly encourage you to reconsider using PolymerFire. It's designed specifically to take the headache out of things like this. Your example would look more like:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<firebase-app api-key="AIzaSyCsZHdalcUQgkhmAkIsnJ66ltkgNakOh20",
  auth-domain="church-of-our-savior-oatlands.firebaseapp.com",
  database-url="https://church-of-our-savior-oatlands.firebaseio.com",
  storage-bucket="church-of-our-savior-oatlands.appspot.com"></firebase-app>

<dom-module id="custom-content">
  <template>
    <firebase-query path="/[[type]]" data="{{posts}}"></firebase-query>

    <span value="[[type]]" id="dummytype"/>
    <h1 class="page-title">[[type]]s</h1>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[posts]]">

      <style>
        :host {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      </style>

      <paper-card elevation="1">
        <p>{{item}}</p>
        <h1 class="page-title" tabindex="-1">{{item.titl}}</h1>
        <h3>{{item.author}}</h3>
        {{item.cont}}
      </paper-card>

    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'custom-content',
    properties: {
      type: {type: String},
      posts: {type: Array}
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'll take a look. I could never get it to load properly. Does it require the firebase.js import or am I all set with just the polymerfire import?

Comment: The PolymerFire import implicitly imports the Firebase JS SDK.

Comment: thank you good sir, i managed to hack this together to work with the rest of my app.